# Cover background-image with transparent background-color

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

I'd like to place a transparent, blue background color over a background image, but I can't seem to get the color to overlay over the image.

**UPDATE:** I changed the margins so that the name takes up 70% and the margins 30%.  However, it doesn't overlay over the two margins. (See updated fiddle)

Any ideas on how?

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="name">
      <h1 id="h" ><a href=#>H</a></h1>
      <h1 id="e" ><a href=#>E</a></h1>
      <h1 id="l" ><a href=#>L</a></h1>
      <h1 id="l2" ><a href=#>L</a></h1>
      <h1 id="o" ><a href=#>O</a></h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
 body {
        font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
        font-size: 75px;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;

        background-color:blue;
        background: url(http://placekitten.com/500/500) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover; 

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    div {
        position:absolute; 
        height:100%; 
        width: 70%;
                margin: 0 15% 0 15%;
        display: table;
    }

    h1 {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align:center;
        height: 1em;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    a {
        /*border: 1px solid black;*/
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }

    a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 3px -3px 0px black;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
        color: white;
    }
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/dQy8A/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amdorra/dQy8A/3/), i hope it helps.

i added a div inside your body

```
<div class = "overlay">
  <div id = "name">
  ....
  </div>
<div>
```

and set it's background color to `background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);` where the last number is the opacity of the color

new css

```
.overlay{
    background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

you should remove the margins from the `div.overlay` and it will work

I also updated the link

P.S. you shouldn't set properties such as `width` and `height` and `display` to a `div` as it will affect all divs on the page and use classes instead of tag names to set those properties

Comment: I know this works in the demo I posted, but it doesn't on my real example even with the exact same code.  Any reason why?

Comment: I updated the question to reflect your changes.  How can I overlay over the margins as well?

Comment: @Keven you could just set the overlay position to fixed like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/amdorra/dQy8A/5/) and it will work

Comment: Yep, that finally did it.  Thanks!